# Prove $\alpha:G\rightarrow H $ is a homomorphism (G,H finite) $\implies$ $|\alpha(G)|$ divides $|G|$ and $|H|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm totally stuck here. Obviously $\alpha(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$, so its order divides the order of $H$, but I don't see how to prove that $|\alpha(G)|$ divides  $|G|$. I've gotten as far as showing that the only case that matters is when $|\alpha(G)|<|G|$, but then I don't have an argument about how distinct terms in $G$ mapping to the same thing in $H$ would somehow work out to make the image of the group have size that's a factor of the size of the group.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the First Isomorphism Theorem for groups? If so, you can try using it in order to know more about the relationship between $G$ and $\alpha(G)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the first isomorphism theorem,
$$\alpha(G)\simeq G/\ker \alpha$$
Thus in particular its size divides $|G|$.

Comment: But doesn't this only work if $\alpha$ is onto? Why are you able to make that assumption?

Comment: $\alpha$ is onto $\alpha(G)$.

Answer (score 3):

By the first isomporphism theorem, $\alpha(G)\cong G/\operatorname{ker}\alpha$.  Thus $|\alpha(G)|||G|$.

Secondly, by Lagrange, since $\alpha(G)$ is a subgroup, $|\alpha(G)|\vert|H|$.